# Compare validator doesn't stop postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, buttonclick, comparevalidator

```
Below is my mark up. 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPatientDateOfBirth" runat="server" 
    CssClass="rightDivInnerControls" ClientIDMode="Static" 
    CausesValidation="True">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvPatientDateOfBirth" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Enter proper date." 
    Type="Date" ControlToValidate="txtPatientDateOfBirth" Font-Bold="True"  
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    ValidationGroup="FirstPreview">
</asp:CompareValidator>    

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" 
    Text="Save Changes"  OnClientClick="return showFinalReviewAlert();" 
    CssClass="btnPrimary hideInPrint btnEditFinalReport" 
    ValidationGroup="FirstPreview" 
    onclick="btnSaveChanges_Click"  ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

When I change the date to a wrong format it shows me the **error message** immediately.

[image]

But when I click on the button "btnSaveChanges" it does a postback. I think something is missing because of which it is doing postback.

Can anyone please help me with the issue. I want to **stop the postback if validation fails**.

Thanks.

Comment: put CausesValidation="True" in button

Comment: @WaqarJanjua [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) is true by default, so that's probably not the solution here.

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes. but i saw on the following post on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx so I ask him to try

Comment: Are you returning `true` from `showFinalReviewAlert`? Because I guess you are overriding the ability of the validator to stop the button click

Comment: try removing the onClientClick

Comment: Added CausesValidation=true to both button and textbox but it did not work.

Comment: Can't remove onClientClick. It does a lot of client side stuff.

Comment: Do you need the result of `showFinalReviewAlert` to effect whether the form is posted back or not?  If **not** then remove the `return`.  If it does then try something like `if(showFinalReviewAlert()==false){return false;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning the value of `showFinalReviewAlert();` in the `OnClientClick` of the button, you are blocking the page validation from happening.

This is effectively the HTML that is being rendered (simplified for viewing)...

```
<input type="submit" 
       id="btnSaveChanges" 
       onclick="return showFinalReviewAlert();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnSaveChanges;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" 
       name="btnSaveChanges">
```

The important bit of this is...

```
onclick="return showFinalReviewAlert();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions....
```

What it means is that no matter what `showFinalReviewAlert()` returns, the `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` will never be reached. However, because it is an `<input type="submit">` the page will post-pack to the server anyway.

So, if the return value of the `showFinalReviewAlert` must stop the post-back from happening by returning the value `false`, you should set the `OnClientClick` attribute as this...

```
OnClientClick="if(showFinalReviewAlert()==false){return false;}"
```

In other words, if `showFinalReviewAlert` return `false` then stop the button from continuing any post-back processing... but if it return `true`, then allow the post-back validation to take place.

On the other hand, if the result of `showFinalReviewAlert()` doesn't matter... simply remove the `return` to give simply...

```
OnClientClick="showFinalReviewAlert();"
```

Comment: Great news @Rain, glad to have helped :-) Best of luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the way these ASP.NET Validators work (described here: [Validating User Input in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx)) is a bit different from what you're expecting - it's supposed to postback.  From the linked MSDN document:

> When the user submits a page to the server, the validation controls
>   are invoked to check the user input, control by control. If a
>   validation error is detected in any of the input controls, **the page
>   itself is set to an invalid state so you can test for validity before
>   your code runs.**

Emphasis mine.  When they say "set the page to an invalid state", they are referring to the [Page.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) property.  So, when you're server-side code runs, you would need to wrap it in a block like this:

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
    // Run code now that validation has been verified.
}
```

In order to prevent a postback entirely, you would need to just use JavaScript (client-side code) in order to disable the submit button until all of your controls are in a valid state.

Comment: @VishalSuthar The OP says "*I think something is missing because of which it is doing postback.*"  I was answering what appears to be the source of confusion - a misunderstanding of how ASP.NET validator controls work.

Comment: @jadarnel27 This solved the problem that brought me to this page and for that I applaud you, sir. You saved me from what had already been a great deal of consternation and helped me get a project that was already overdue finished today...

Answer (score 2):

Add OnClientClick as well as Onclick event in your server control asp:button,

**asp:Button** ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" **OnClientClick**="if(validateTotal()==false){return false;}"

If function OnClientClick event will return false then it will not postback.

your validateTotal() may be like this,

```
function validateTotal() 
{
    if (parseInt($('.lblTotal').text().trim()) > 100) {
        alert("Please check total value, it should not be more than 100%");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `ValidationGroup` in the `TextBox` control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPatientDateOfBirth" runat="server" 
    CssClass="rightDivInnerControls" ClientIDMode="Static" 
    CausesValidation="True"
    ValidationGroup="FirstPreview">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used:

```
OnClientClick="return showFinalReviewAlert();"
```

What you are doing in `showFinalReviewAlert();"`?

What you can do inside `showFinalReviewAlert();"` is add  `return false` that will stop Postback of the page.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showFinalReviewAlert() {
        //
        //   Your coding stuffs...
        //
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There are lot of client side stuff in showFinalReviewAlert(). Can't remove this :(

Comment: Thanks for your time. I got the answer. I need to return true/false from showFinalReviewAlert() conditionally.