# Validation controls distorts UI

Tags: asp.net, css, styles, validation

I checked with firebug and found that error messages shown by validation controls are rended as span and visibility: hidden; style is applied to them in order to make them invisible.
Because of visibility: hidden; style the space for the error message is reserved and this distorts the UI.

Check this image[image]

I checked with firebug and got to know if we apply display:none instead of visibility:hidden this UI distortion will be fixed. But I don't know how to apply this style as the span for error message is created internally and the style applied is inline.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Display="Dynamic"` attribute on your validators.

This should use the `display:none` style instead of `display:hidden`

[More information from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: You're welcome @Rain. Hope my answer to your [other validator question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688399/compare-validator-doesnt-stop-postback) is also useful to you

Comment: Yes, it really helped me out.