# return confirm inside gridview does not fire

Tags: asp.net

In my code pasted below the grid has an option to delete the row on click of remove button. Before hitting server side code i want to confirmation from the user to delete the record.

But always server side code is hit rather than the confirm popup showing first.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdDelegateList" runat="server" CssClass="gridviewBorder" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CellPadding="1" Style="margin-left: 0px" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Calibri"
                    BorderWidth="1px" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="Horizontal" RowHoverBackColor="#666666"
                    RowHoverForeColor="White" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#333333" SelectedRowStyle-ForeColor="White"
                    PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="grdDelegateList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="grdDelegateList_RowCommand"
                    OnRowDataBound="grdDelegateList_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdDelegateList_RowDeleting">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee ID" DataField="DelegateID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <p>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Owner.FirstName")%>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Owner.LastName")%>
                                </p>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span style="cursor: pointer">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ImgRemove" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                                        Text="Remove" OnClientClick="return confirm(Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate);">
                                    </asp:LinkButton></span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

What i want to do is show a confirm box if user presses the on button server side code (ie: row command ) event should be hit, other wise on cancel it should do nothing. but its not working.

Comment: Check this question's answer, might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688399/compare-validator-doesnt-stop-postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to add single quotes to the OnClientClick

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate');
```

you can also try the following code:

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate')) return false;"
```

Comment: This worked because of the `'` around the text within the `confirm()` method. There is no reason that you need to add the `if` into the `OnClientClick`. `confirm()` represents a boolean so you should always use the code `return confirm('text');`

Answer (score 1):

Your code for the `confirm()` function is not valid.

`confirm()` expects a string variable ([see window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm)) yet in your case you are passing in an invalid object and would receive the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Update your code to be;

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="ImgRemove" 
    runat="server" 
    CommandName="Delete" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
    Text="Remove" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ImgRemove" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Remove" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate?'));">
```

- `OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate?'));`
  will show the alert with Yes/No options. If you click on No then nothing will happen. If you click on Yes then corresponding code will execute